# How to mount extra disk on same directory on Azure VM?

Tags: azure

I have one attached 1TB disk on Azure VM that storage ll be full in some time.
I want to attach second 1TB SSD disk on Azure VM and want to mount on the same directory without losing any data.
can anyone give me steps for this?

Comment: Your VM is Linux or Windows VM?

Comment: vm is linux based

Comment: You use managed disk or unmanaged disk? According to your scenario, I suggest you had better resize your data disk to 2TB.

Comment: You could not mount two disk on a directory except you use lvm, but you need re-create file system, it will lose your data.

Comment: If you use managed disk, it is easy for you to resize your data disk size.

Comment: I'm using an unmanaged disk that is the problem so I can't resize unmanaged disk.

Comment: If you use unmanaged disk, you also could resize data disk, please check my answer.

Comment: yes, we can resize unmanaged and managed data disk using portal but how to mount that  increased size to existing partition in unmanaged

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the OS or data disk to 4TB now. That's the best way assuming 4TB will be enough for your use case, otherwise, I suggest creating a virtual disk with Storage Spaces using multiple data disks and copying the content over.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk

After that, you also have to expand the disk in the operating system.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771473(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_WINUI

If the partition style for your disk is set to MBR, then 2TB will be the maximum size supported, no matter what you have in Azure. To be able to use 4TB disks in a single partition, you need to use GPT.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Azure VM OS type, if your VM is Windows series, you could use Bruno Faria's steps. If you use Linux VM, you could not mount multiple disks on the same directory, your data will lose. Please refer to this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/mounting-multiple-devices-at-a-single-mount-point-on-linux).

You could add a new disk to Azure VM and mount disk to subdirectory. It is same with you mount first disk to your VM and does not lose any data.

Another solution is as Bruno Farid said, you could resize your original disk to a larger size. Please refer to this [link:How to expand virtual hard disks on a Linux VM with the Azure CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/expand-disks).

```
az disk update \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myDataDisk \
    --size-gb 2048
```

Note: It works for managed disk.

Update:

If you VM use unmanaged disk, you also could resize your data disk to 2TB.

1.Stop your VM.

2.Resize data disk to 2048GB. You could find it on Azure Portal.`Your VM`-->`Disks`

[image]

3.Start your VM.

4.SSH to your VM and expand disk. Please refer to the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/expand-disks). Start at step 5.

Comment: @Tailor Devendra You also could resize unmanaged disk size. I test in my lab, it does not lose data.

Comment: I tried this link earlier but this command `az disk list \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --query '[*].{Name:name,Gb:diskSizeGb,Tier:accountType}' \
    --output table` is not showing me unmanaged disk list

Comment: @TailorDevendra Sorry for the later reply. You use unmanaged disk, the output should be null.

Comment: @TailorDevendra You could re-larger your disk on Azure Portal.

Comment: issue not solved yet. Above solution is worked for managed but not for unmanaged.

Comment: @TailorDevendra You need resize the disk inside your VM, please refer this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/expand-disks). Start at step 5. I test in my lab, it works for me.

Comment: Hi, do you check the link, you need start at `sudo umount /dev/sdc1`. I test in my lab, I don't lose my data. If possible, you had better backup your data and do these steps.

Comment: i'll try tonight and let you know.

Comment: I know that your solution always works for me and it 'll also work but I'm little busy with other things so I can't accept it without a trial. I'll accept it as an answer that is sure.

Comment: @TailorDevendra Hi, do you solve this?